# How to avoid options reset after changing an option for a configurable product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a configurable product with 3 options (all dropdowns).

The first problem is that only the first dropdown is active but other 2 remain inactive until the first is selected. How to enable all the dropdowns?

The second problem is that if I select all 3 options and then, change 1 option, I have to select again the other 2 options. How to save the other chosen options?
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is default behavior for configurable products. Swatches however do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

You can either change the attributes into swatches or overwrite the configurable template to use the swatch template instead.

[This](https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/251) is a related community feature issue requesting this feature.

My company created a [module](https://github.com/iMi-digital/magento2-module-always-swatch-selects) to overwrite the configurable template with the swatch template so you could either use the module or use it as guidance on how to implement your own solution.